# Copying Worksheet to Worksheet - how to copy only the value?

Tags: worksheet

```
Sub Sample()

Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set wsI = Sheets("EC6")
Set wsO = Sheets("2")

 LastRow = wsI.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

j = 1

With wsI
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        wsI.Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(j)

        j = j + 1
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

How do I copy only the VALUE from wsI to wsO ?

Answer (score 0):

If your destination worksheets already exist (i.e. you have 31 worksheets, named 1 to 31):

```
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set wsI = Sheets("EC6")

Set wsO = Sheets(wsI.Cells(49, 1).Value)

LastRow = wsI.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

j = 1

With wsI
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        wsI.Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(j)

        j = j + 1
    Next i
End With
```